# How do I synchronise digikam between different PCs?

Tags: digikam, sync

I copied the digikam database files from my PC to my laptop, but digikam ignored them and recreated its database.
How can I copy the digikam data back to the PC without the same thing happening?
The issue arises because digikam assigns a unique volume identifier to each disk. I tried following the recommended procedure:- Open digikam; change collection from internal disk to removeable disk.
It didn’t work. digikam did exactly what I described in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I can transform my database among computers by changing uuid in digikam4.db and thumbnails-digikam.db to suite the paths in the new drive. Download the program in [this (old) post](https://manurevah.com/blah/en/blog/Digikam-When-Your-Path-Changes), then "Find and Replace" old paths to the new ones.